# Represent every Integer number as a summation/subtraction of distinct power of 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am working on a homework question that asks to prove that every Integer (including zero) can be calculated in the form $\sum_{k}\pm3^{k}$, where the exponents $k$ are distinct non-negative integers.

I wanted to make sure I am not missing something obvious. What I found was that
$\sum_{k}\pm3^{k}\neq0$ when k is distinct.
$$3^{0} = 1$$
$$-3^{0} = -1$$ 
$$-3^{1} + 3^{0} = -2$$
As far as I can tell, there is no way for this expression to equal zero because every other combination will be $\geq 1$ or $\leq -1$.  Does this sound correct and if so, what is the correct proof method I can use?  I was think proof by counter example.

I found a very similar [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119606/represent-every-natural-number-as-a-summation-subtraction-of-distinct-power-of), where sdcvvc pointed out that it was possible if you can represent any number n as $a_{k}3^{k}+a_{k-1}3^{k−1}+⋯+a_{1}3+a_{0}$, such that $a_{i}$∈{−1,0,1}.  But without $a_{i}=0$, I don't see how it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the [referenced thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119606/42969) it is demonstrated that every integer $n$ can be written as a sum
$$
 n = a_{k}3^{k}+a_{k-1}3^{k−1}+ \ldots +a_{1}3+a_{0}
$$
where $a_i \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$ for $i=0, \ldots, k$. If we denote the indices of non-zero coefficients with $I$
$$
 I = \{ i \mid a_i \in \{ -1, 1 \}
$$
then
$$
 n = \sum_{i \in I} a_i 3^i
$$
is the representation of $n$ as a sum and difference of distinct powers of $3$.

If $n= 0$ then all $a_i$ are zero and $I$ is the empty set. In this case $\sum_{i \in I} a_i 3^i$ is the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) which – by convention – evaluates to zero.

Comment: I see, thank you.  In that case, what would be the best way to prove it?  Proof by induction with one case for positive integers and another case for negative integers?

Comment: @MathProblems...: There is a proof in the Q&A that you referenced, e.g. this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119613/42969.